# SSM Parameter Store to set Beanstalk Environment Variables

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-ssm

I have a spring-boot micro-service running on a AWS beanstalk.

I am trying to set some environment variables for beanstalk environment, however I am not sure how to fetch the value of the beanstalk environment variables from SSM parameter store.

I have explored .ebextensions option and I do not want to bake my environment configuration with code. Wanted to keep configuration separate from the code.

I am not a fan of customizing my spring-boot app to use AWS to fetch SSM paramter store either.

Any pointers will help!

Comment: You can set the environment variables in the beanstalk console under: your environment -> configuration -> software.  They can be then assessed as usual in spring's app properties via `${..}`.

Comment: Thanks @StefanN, yes but I want to get the value of those environment variables from SSM parameter store

Comment: For that you can use, e.g., spring-cloud-starter-aws-parameter-store-config or the full Spring Cloud Starter AWS. That let's you connect to the parameter store and retrieve the properties.

Comment: Thanks @StefanN that is a good solution, however we do not want our microservices to depend on AWS services as they will be deployed to other cloud environments as well.
However, for now I have used appspec and ebextentions to inject properties. And is working on a more centralized configuration server.